# WordPress: Asset URLs wrong when not logged in

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, wordpress-theming

I ran into a pretty strange problem while setting up a website. I moved a WP installation from the subdirectory wp2014 to the website root (the site is http://www.startglobal.org/), and now all the links still go to the subdirectory. The weird thing is that everything is displayed correctly once I am logged in as an admin.

Would anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks!
Benjamin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try [WP Migrate DB](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) Plugin, hopefully It should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, the find and replace on my DB fixed everything!

Comment: Your Welcome. I am happy that you find my answer helpful.